# How to compute adjusted-R squared in MATLAB with no parameters of fit?

Tags: matlab, statistics, regression

I have a spectrum fitted in LIFBASE and imported in MATLAB, together with the experimental spectrum. I used rsquare function to compute R<sup>2</sup>, but I would also like to get adjusted-R<sup>2</sup>. Is there a way to do it with built-in functions?

Comment: Is it not just a matter of [using an equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2)?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37001725/6469393) and page 212 of [this book](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/), I take this definition for adjusted-R<sup>2</sup>:

[image]

where `p` is the total number of explanatory variables in the model (not including the constant term), and `n` is the sample size.

Let me make it clear: If you have no information about the fitted model, **you cannot calculate adjusted-R<sup>2</sup>.**

Besides, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2):

> Adjusted R<sup>2</sup> does not have the same interpretation as R<sup>2</sup>—while R<sup>2</sup> is a measure of fit, adjusted R<sup>2</sup> is instead a comparative measure of suitability of alternative nested sets of explanators.